# Can I see who gifted me a game after I accepted the gift?

Tags: steam

I would like to send a thank you gift to the several people who were kind enough to gift me Steam games throughout the last year.

Is it possible to see who gifted you a particular game? If so, how?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Steam has a built in log of *what* was gifted to you, under "___'s Account -> Account Details -> Licenses and Subscriptions". However, this doesn't list *who* gifted them to you. There doesn't seem to be any way to get at this information from inside Steam.

The best way seems to be to check your mail; every time you're sent a gift, Steam sends you a message at the email address it has on file. Look for messages from a @steampowered.com address with "received a gift" in the subject line.